# HOW TO INSTALL ofbiz ON UBUNTU12.04?

Tags: 12.04

I want to install ofbiz on my laptop.I installed ubuntu 12.04 GUI version.Can anybody help me out???I tried so many procedure from internet,but every time i failed.

Comment: You might want to talk about the process of installation you have tried so far, and what error messages you have gotten so far. While someone may not have specific knowledge of ofbiz, many or these error messages are generic. Help us help you. Don't forget to mention the version of ofbiz you are using, and whether this is through a repo (official or PPA) or from source!

Comment: Which java have you installed? `java -version`

Answer (score 4):

1. Download ofbiz https://ofbiz.apache.org/download.html
2. Check your Java installed: `java -version` Output should be: java version "1.7.0_21"
3. Next go to directory where you should find: apache-ofbiz-12.04.01.zip
4. unpack ofbiz: `unzip apache-ofbiz-12.04.01.zip`
5. Build ofBiz with Demo data: `./ant load-demo` will take about 20 minutes
6. Next start ofbiz: `./ant start`
7. As per README file open in browser: `[http://localhost:8080/ecommerce/]` to look at the demo storefront and open administration interface at `[https://localhost:8443/webtools]`

Comment: Java install: `sudo apt-get install default-jdk`

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** After downloading the jdk file open the terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> for navigate to the file.
    (you can use **sudo apt-get install nautilus-open-terminal** for open Terminal in Any location)

```
tar -xf jdk-7u75-linux-i586.tar.gz
```

This will extract and create a jdk folder at your current path(jdk-7u75-linux-i586.tar.gz is my jdk file name).

**Step 2:** Create a location to keep your new JDK . I prefer and usually use `/usr/lib/jvm/`

You may need root permission to create the `/usr/lib/jvm` (hence use sudo).

```
sudo mkdir /usr/lib/jvm
```

**Step 3:** Move the extracted jdk folder to `/usr/lib/jvm/`

```
sudo mv jdk1.7.0_75 /usr/lib/jvm/
```

**Step 4:** Now we have to setup our system to use refer to our new jdk

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_75/bin/java" 1 
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

And also register Firefox Java Plugin

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libjavaplugin.so" "mozilla-javaplugin.so" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_75/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so" 1 
sudo update-alternatives --config mozilla-javaplugin.so
```

ALL DONE. You can test your java install by Type  `java -version`

Then Same way for Apache ant:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/ant" "ant" "/usr/lib/jvm/apache-ant-1.9.2/bin/ant" 1
sudo update-alternatives --config ant
```

You can test your ant install by `ant -version`

Then Set Path: For java path setup go to terminal & type: `sudo nano /etc/environment`

Set JAVA_HOME  ANT_HOME & PATH as like given. Save & Close the Terminal

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_75" ANT_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/apache-ant-1.9.2"
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_75/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/apache-ant-1.9.2/bin"
```

**Step 5:** After installing Apache OFBiz, Use following command to start Apache OFBiz service on system: Go to The OfBiz Folder Directory & open TERMINAL Then type the following Command:

1. `sudo ant clean-all`
2. `sudo ant load-demo`
3. `sudo ant load-extseed` // this is not mendotory; it is used for changes of Entity
4. `sudo ant start` // This will Start Apache OFBiz Service

**Step 6:** Access Apache OFBiz in Browser

Access Apache OFBiz in browser on port 8443 as below given url and login credentials.

URL: **https://localhost:8443/humanres/control/main**

Admin Username: **admin**

Admin Password: **ofbiz**

Thats All Done...................!